# unable to increase average throughput in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have set the number of threads and ramp-up time to 1/1 and I am iterating my 1000 records from data.csv for 1800 seconds.
Now given the numbers, I have set the CTT, constant time throughput to 2000 every minute and I expected the average throughput to be 2000/60 = 33.3/sec, but I get 18.7/sec, when I increased the throughput to 4000/60, I still get 18 or 19/sec.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To gain enough throughput, CTT needs enough threads. Try to increase the thread.

Comment: what is the ideal value in my case, I have set thread/rampup to 1000/0 and the avg throughput is like 70/sec, 30/sec, 29/sec etc..

Comment: Thread 1000 is way too much I presume. Use as much as you need. Maybe ~100 would be enough for to reach the throughput 33.3/sec as u mentioned. And try not to use the ramp up time as 0.

Comment: I have now set this to 100/6 and CTT to 4000/min and avg throughput is like  13.5/s, 6/s, 7.3/s whereas I expect this to improve, I don't understand the relation b/w threads/sec and CTT, I thought CTT would override the threads/sec number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant Throughput Timer cannot force threads to execute faster, it can only **pause** threads to **limit** JMeter's throughput to the defined value.

Each JMeter thread executes samplers as fast as it can, however next iteration won't start until previous is finished so given you use 1 thread - the throughput won't be higher than application response time.

Also be aware that Constant Throughput Timer is accurate enough on **minute** level so you can rather manipulate "requests per minute" rather than "requests per second", if your test is shorter than 1 minute - consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

So I would recommend increasing the number of virtual users to i.e. 50.

See [How to use JMeter's Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your application average response time is around 50ms. Which means a single thread can only perform about 20 hits/sec (1 sec / 0.05 sec per hit = 20 hits/sec).

You have 2 solutions:

- increase the number of threads to parallelize requests sent,
- or make you app response faster (obviously harder).

At some point, when you application can't handle more load, you should see the hits/sec dropping and the average response time increase.

The graph below shows you an example of application which has a steady response time with up to 20 concurrent threads.

[image: Sample graph showing response time and hits]